# Remove first n word from line

Tags: c, regex

This line:

```
anyWord = this is a placeholder to the end of line
```

I want to remove `anyWord =`  and get the rest of the line.

Comment: `Name = ` does not look like one word

Comment: This seems like it would be more readily solved with the inbuilt string functions in whichever language you are using. For example, split on `=` and take the second part.

Comment: I use C language

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you wish to use only regex to solve this:

`(?:^\w+ = )(.*)$`

and then take the capturing group (group 1).

Comment: Thanks. that's so close. but I don't mean "Name" I mean may "word+space+equal sign+space". I just updated the question

Comment: thank you for your time. but that still doesn't work with me, I don't know why. check this: https://regexr.com/

Comment: https://bpa.st/IZEQ I so close and the output okay, I don't like that I use `char x[1]` to skip that...

Answer (score 0):

While not using a regex, we can use strtok to get the right side of the `=` char in a given line:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char* getRightSideOfEquals(const char* line){

    char* linecopy = strdup(line);
    const char* result = NULL;
    char* left = strtok(linecopy, "=");
    const char* right = strtok(NULL, "=");

    while (right && isspace(*right)) {  // remove whitespace
        right++;
    }

    result = strdup(right ? right : "");
    free((void*)linecopy);
    return result;
}


int main()
{
    const char* line = "anyWord = this is a placeholder to the end of line";
    const char* right = getRightSideOfEquals(line);
    printf("%s\n", right);
    free((void*)right);
    return 0;
}
```

The above program will print: `this is a placeholder to the end of line`